# Error when using javascript ternary operator with knockout secure binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When I use [knockout-secure-binding](https://github.com/brianmhunt/knockout-secure-binding) with ko, and I try to use ternary operators inside data-bind, an error occurs.

Sample code:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { class: itemSelected() ? 'selected' : 'unselected' }"></div>​
```

KSB init:

```
var options = {
   attribute: "data-bind",        // default "data-sbind"
   globals: window,               // default {}
   bindings: ko.bindingHandlers,  // default ko.bindingHandlers
   noVirtualElements: false       // default true
};
ko.bindingProvider.instance = new ko.secureBindingsProvider(options);
```

Error:

```
Uncaught #<Object> knockout-secure-binding.js: 4
```

If I use the regular binder, without including the secure one, everything works as expected. Why is this happening? What can I do to keep using secure binding?

Comment: And what's the problem? This doesn't make sense as a question

Comment: The problem is I am using knockout secure binding. and it will produce that error above @JotaBe

Comment: what happens if you change `data-bind` to `data-sbind`

Comment: also, please show how you initialise ksb

Comment: @ArdenLatraca Yep, that's obvious. But this isn't a problem, but an specification of sbind. Please, see my answer for an alternative.

Comment: I added my initialization above @Alex

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find out alternative way @JotaBe

Comment: @ArdenLatraca Although I could seem rude, my intention was that your question was more direct, as it is now. Your original question was a kind of "I have a problem.Thanks" ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's natural that it doesn't work. If you see the expressions section of [the specs of `sbind`](https://github.com/brianmhunt/knockout-secure-binding), , which is the language that you can use in data bindings when you use the secure bind binder, you'll see that the ternary operator isn't in the list.

You'll have to use a [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) or [pure computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html) that evaluates that expression, and bind the computed instead of the expression.

The computed could be like this:

```
self.selClass = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.itemSelected() ? 'selected' : 'unselected';
}, self);
```

*NOTE: you can use a pure computed. This example shows the case of a view model created with a constructor that uses the `self=this` pattern. If you use other patter for your view model, like RMP, the computed will be slightly different*

So, the binding woul be this one:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { class: selClass }"></div>​
```

which is a valid `sbind` expression.

Comment: oh this would be a good alternative way. forgot how computed works lol. thanks @JotaBe

Comment: @Alex Thank you for your "fair play" and comment ;)  The OP really needed it!!